# PHP + JS validation not working

Tags: javascript, php, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I have written a talent contact form where I have used both jQuery validation as well as custom PHP validation for form fields.

Both were tested working ok on all browsers [ not below ie 8] during development phase.

It is now live.
From the usages log we find **in very few cases**  the validation is not working properly and probably on the following particular field. Some users were able to submit the form without choosing that particular field.

Can you point out/ suggest where is the problem? I'm trying to contact users who somehow bypassed the validation and know what's happening on their device and also their browser version. Also they seem nontechnical and genuine users. So attempt of hacking through form inputs is not likely the case.

Thanks to all for your time and effort

The bypassed input field

```
<div class="BNF_input_row">
    <label for="BNF_select_talent" class="BNF_input_label">
        Select Your Talent (required)
    </label>
    <select multiple="true" tabindex="106" class="input" id="BNF_select_talent" value="" name="BNF_select_talent[]" onclick="addTalentScdriptOption()" onblur="addTalentScdriptOption()" >
        <?php  echo BNF_Booking::getTalentList(); ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

---

js validation code

```
var vlidation_option ={
   rules: {
     BNF_your_name: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 2
     },
     BNF_your_comp: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 3
     },
     BNF_your_email: {
       required: true,
       email: true
     },
     BNF_your_phone: {
       required: true,
     },
     'BNF_select_talent[]': {
       required: true,
     },
     BNF_choose_format: {
       required: true,
     },
     BNF_master_script: {
       extension: "doc|docx"
     },

   },
   messages: {
     BNF_your_name: {
       required: "Required",
       minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required!")
     },
     BNF_your_comp: {
       required: "Required",
       minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required!")
     },
     BNF_your_email: {
       required: "Required",
       email: jQuery.format("that email is not valid!")
     },
     BNF_your_phone: {
       required: "Required",
               phoneUS: "Not valid phone number"
     },
     'BNF_select_talent[]': {
       required: "Required",
     },
     BNF_choose_format: {
       required: "Required",
     },
     BNF_master_script: {
               extension: "only .doc and .docx files are accepted"
     },
   },


};
jQuery("#BNF_booking_form").validate(vlidation_option);
```

---

PHP validation

```
public static function verifyData($data){
    $response = array();
    $response['status'] = "";
    $iserror = false;
    if(!isset($data['name']) || trim($data['name']) == ''){
        $response['status'] .= "Enter your name\n";
        $iserror = TRUE;
    }
    if(!isset($data['comp']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
        $response['status'] .= "Enter your company\n";
        $iserror = TRUE;
    }
    if(!isset($data['email']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
        $response['status'] .= "Enter your email\n";
        $iserror = TRUE;
    }
    if(!isset($data['phone']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
        $response['status'] .= "Enter your phone\n";
        $iserror = TRUE;
    }
    if(!isset($data['talent']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
        $response['status'] .= "Select talent(s) for the job\n";
        $iserror = TRUE;
    }
    if(!isset($data['script']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
        $response['status'] .= "Attach scripts for talents\n";
        $iserror = TRUE;
    }
    if(!$iserror){
        $response['status'] = "YES";
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: About the JS part, as you think it may related to their browser/version. Anyway, PHP validation must secure your process. There is a missing PHP validation concerning the field "BNF_select_talent". It's your problem.

Comment: $data = array();
$data['name'] = $_POST['BNF_your_name'];
$data['comp'] = $_POST['BNF_your_comp'];
$data['email'] = $_POST['BNF_your_email'];
$data['phone'] = $_POST['BNF_your_phone'];
$data['rush'] = $_POST['BNF_is_rush'];
$data['talent'] = $_POST['BNF_select_talent'];
$data['format'] = $_POST['BNF_choose_format'];
$data['instruct'] = $_POST['BNF_special_instruct'];
$data['script'] = array();
$data['master_script'] = '';

Answer (score 0):

Just debug it.

Use Firefox console + Firebug. In Javascript write out your variables with

```
console.log("Testing var1: " + var1);
```

And you will see it in the console log.

PS: Also, I am not sure, but check the validation options. Are you really really sure you need the squared brackets after BNF_select_talent in there?

```
'BNF_select_talent[]': { <===
   required: true,
 },
'BNF_select_talent[]': { <===
   required: "Required",
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP, looks like you need to trim and validate talent instead of comp, try this:

Replace this,

```
if(!isset($data['email']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
    $response['status'] .= "Enter your email\n";
    $iserror = TRUE;
}
if(!isset($data['phone']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
    $response['status'] .= "Enter your phone\n";
    $iserror = TRUE;
}
if(!isset($data['talent']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
    $response['status'] .= "Select talent(s) for the job\n";
    $iserror = TRUE;
}
if(!isset($data['script']) || trim($data['comp']) == ''){
    $response['status'] .= "Attach scripts for talents\n";
    $iserror = TRUE;
}
```

With,

```
if(!isset($data['email']) || trim($data['email']) == ''){
    $response['status'] .= "Enter your email\n";
    $iserror = TRUE;
}
if(!isset($data['phone']) || trim($data['phone']) == ''){
    $response['status'] .= "Enter your phone\n";
    $iserror = TRUE;
}
if(!isset($data['talent']) || trim($data['talent']) == ''){
    $response['status'] .= "Select talent(s) for the job\n";
    $iserror = TRUE;
}
if(!isset($data['script']) || trim($data['script']) == ''){
    $response['status'] .= "Attach scripts for talents\n";
    $iserror = TRUE;
}
```

For JS, try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("talentRequired", function (value, element) {
    var count = $(element).find('option:selected').length;
    return count > 0;
});
```

And replace,

```
'BNF_select_talent[]': {
    required: true,
},
```

With,

```
'BNF_select_talent[]': "required talentRequired",
```